# Setting current node url as default value for "Link" field

Tags: navigation

I have a content type with a field type [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link). I would like to set default text and url for the field. Under:

> Structure » Content types » MY CONTENT TYPE » Manage fields

I tried entering `#` and `[current-page:url:absolute]`. Both of them were not accepted and the below are the respective error messages:

- The value `[current-page:url:absolute]` provided for MY FIELD NAME is not a valid URL.
- The value `#` provided for MY FIELD NAME is not a valid URL.

What is the right way to enter the current node URL as a default value into a Link type field?

Comment: you can do by using rules module

Comment: Are you doing it in code, or on settings form? If in code, please post your code. If in settings form, please post a screenshot.

Comment: @Mołot added additional info to the question.

Comment: What Drupal version? [If 8, this is not yet possible](https://www.drupal.org/node/1070878).

Comment: I am using Druapl 7

Comment: try using  #[site:current-page:?] this will work

Comment: @VimalGoradiya same issue it didn't work...

Comment: you need to use module [field default token](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_default_token) to work global as well local token.

Comment: @VimalGoradiya you should make your comment into an answer, I just tried the module and it does allow you to enter token values for link fields default values. And it worked with the `[current-page:url:absolute]` token as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use module [field default token](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_default_token) to work global as well local token in field value. You can use your previous token i.e. `[current-page:url:absolute]`.